# iPhone ScrollView in Tab Bar Controller - ScrollView doesn't scroll. Can someone help?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a ScrollView to a Tab Bar Controller. Problem is the ScrollView won't scroll, and I can't for the life of me find out why on Google. If I replace the ScrollView with a TextView, that one scrolls, and so does a TableView.

You can get the code demonstrating this from here: git://gitorious.org/scrollview-in-tabbar-project/scrollview-in-tabbar-project.git

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please notice that, annoyingly, the TextView that is inside the ScrollView scrolls. Not sure if this is related, but I don't get a viewWillAppear call when I select the ScrollView's tab.

Comment: Is the contentsize of the content in your scrollview actually bigger than the bounds of the scrollview itself? if not; the scrollview will not scroll (because it doesn't have to).

Comment: How do I find that out? Visually, the content is larger than the ScrollView, but I don't know how to confirm this in code. That's why I posted the sources on gitorious: hoping someone will take a look at it and hit me with a straight solution and enlighten me.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I've already trawled the docs and Google, and I posted this question here because I ran out of ideas. I posted the simplest project I could come up with hoping to get a simple and direct answer after RTFM-ing and not getting anywhere. I artificially enlarged the content so it doesn't fit on the screen by any margin, and I still can't scroll the ScrollView. My assumption is that the ScrollView itself won't get bigger than the screen.

Comment: I hinted to the docs because you asked about the contentSize; which is in there. I don't know how to retrieve your Git project since I am inexperienced with Git, so I can not take a look at the code itself.

Comment: @MiRAGe Thanks for trying to help. FWIW, XCode has GIT support built-in. Go to File -> Source Control -> Repositories... (it opens the Organizer into the "Repositories" tab). In the bottom left corner of this window there's a button with a "plus" sign and the menu has "Checkout or clone repository", and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set the `contentSize` of your scrollview. You are responsible to set the `contentSize` property. In your case, you can add this to `viewDidLoad` in your `SecondViewController`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)self.view;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1024);
}
```

Set the height of the `contentSize` to what ever fits your needs (possibly you have to calculate the height to fit what you are putting in the scrollview).

Here's an example from the Apple documentation: [Creating Scroll Views in Interface Builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html)

Comment: Hey, that made it scroll! Cheers! I expected it to detect this on its own for some reason.

Comment: @MiRAGe Yes, that's why I voted your first comment up. All the Googling I did came up with similar suggestions, but I tripped upon myself for various reasons: I didn't find the right man pages (Erik pointed to a page I haven't seen, which says straight away I'm responsible for that setting), viewWillAppear isn't emitted (and thinking I was doing something wrong I didn't try viewDidLoad). I wanted a quick and to the point answer, since I was obviously not understanding what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Erik Tjernlund's answer, my code now looks like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat maxDepth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < scrollView.subviews.count; i++)
    {
        UIView *aSubview = (UIView *) [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat depth = aSubview.frame.origin.y + aSubview.frame.size.height;
        if (depth > maxDepth)
            maxDepth = depth;
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, maxDepth);
}
```

and right now it looks like it satisfies my needs. It's also probably not 100% correct, and I'll find that out as I go deeper.